# Change text on link while loading

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp button that while processing i would like the text on it.. How could achieve that?

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="loadImages" runat="server" CssClass="button"
       onclick="loadImages_Click">Load Images</asp:LinkButton>
```

So when I click, it will change the Load Images to Loading... and then go back to the original state once it finishes.

I would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: This is a server side control - the `onclick` will execute on the _server_. Are you looking to do this client side?

Comment: ***and then go back to the original state once it finishes.*** - what finishes?!

Comment: and what are using to load, ajax, client script, updatepanel

Comment: the on click does all the server side (like gets the images etc..).. any way that you think will work i will try, thank you for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[OnClientClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.onclientclick.aspx)...

```
<asp:LinkButton OnClientClick="this.innerHTML = 'loading'" ...
```

Once the page posts back the text will revert to "Load Images"

Answer (score 1):

To change the text of a link *when a user clicks on it* use the `onclick` JavaScript event:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var link = document.getElementById('<%=loadImages.ClientID %>');

    link.addEventListener('click', function(){
        this.innerHTML = 'loading ...';
    }, false);
}, false);
```

This snippet will change the text of the link before the request to the server is made. Once the server responds the page will refresh with the newly rendered HTML from the response.